# Drawing text on line link d3.js simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

so I am simply trying to attach text, represented through data.link (the edge variable), to my links between nodes. I have searched extensively online, but none of the examples I have found work for my code. Attached is my code and a screenshot of what the display looks like.

[Sample output of given code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gRAi.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<style>
.links line {
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-opacity: 0.99;
}
.node text {
stroke:#ffffff;
cursos:pointer;
}
.nodes circle {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<jsp:include page = "/header.jsp"/>
<script>
var width = 2000,
height = 1000
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);


var toString = JSON.stringify(${json});
 console.log(toString);
var data = JSON.parse(toString);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; 
}).distance(300))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(1000, 500));

var link = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(data.links)
  .enter().append("line")
.attr("fill", "black")
.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
.attr("id",function(d,i) {return 'link  '+i});




var node = svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "nodes")
 .selectAll("circle")
 .data(data.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
         return "translate(" + width/12 + "," + height/12 + ")";
       })
 .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("link")
.data(data.links)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("id",function(d,i) { return "linkid_" + i; });


var labelText = svg.selectAll(".labelText")
.data(data.links)
.enter().append("text")
.attr("class","labelText")
.attr("dx",20)
.attr("dy",0)
.style("fill","red")
.append("textPath")
.attr("xlink:href",function(d,i) { return "#linkid_" + i;})
.text(function(d) { return d.edge;});


node.append("circle")
.attr("r", 75)
.style("stroke-width", 3)
.style("stroke", function(d){
    //is in query
    if(d.queried)
        return "ffff00"
    //is not in query
    else
        return "black"
})
.attr("fill", function(d){ 
        //is a person
        if(d.name != null)
            return "#00ccff";
        //is a message
        else
            return "#006666";
                    });



simulation
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);
simulation.force("link")
    .links(data.links);


node.append("text")
.attr("class","system")
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) {
  return d.name;
 });

node.append("text")
.attr("class","system")
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("dx", -15)
.attr("dy",20)
.text(function(d) {
  return d.gender;
 });

//only append id if a person
node.append("text")
.attr("class","system")
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("dx", -20)
.attr("dy",40)
.text(function(d) {
    if(d.name != null)
  return d.id;
 });

//Add message if is message type
node.append("text")
.attr("class","system")
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("dx", -50)
.attr("dy", -20)
.text(function(d) {
    if(d.name == null)
  return d.message.substring(0,15);
 });

//Add message if is message type
node.append("text")
.attr("class","system")
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("dx", -50)
.attr("dy", -5)
.text(function(d) {
    if(d.name == null)
  return d.message.substring(15,30);
 });

//Add message if is message type
node.append("text")
.attr("class","system")
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("dx", -50)
.attr("dy", 10)
.text(function(d) {
    if(d.name == null)
  return d.message.substring(30,45);
 });

//Add message if is message type
node.append("text")
.attr("class","system")
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("dx", -50)
.attr("dy", 25)
.text(function(d) {
    if(d.name == null)
  return d.message.substring(45,60) + "...";
 });


function ticked() {
link
.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
node
.attr("transform",function(d){return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});



}
  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }
  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }
  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
```

Comment: Why exactly none of the examples worked? There is no mystery here: convert those lines to paths and use textpaths for the texts.

Comment: Forgive me, I am a bit of a beginner, but something like this right?

Comment: var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data.links)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
    .attr("id",function(d,i) {return 'link '+i});

Comment: var labelText = svg.append("g")
.data(data.links)
.append("textPath")
.attr("xlink:href",function(d,i) { return "#linkid_" + i;})
.text(function(d) { return d.edge;});

Comment: Yes, that's the most common approach.

Comment: Am I forgetting something else? What I have is still not working based upon those changes. Thank you so much for your help by the way

Comment: A path doesn't have a x1, x2, y1 or y2 properties. Since you changed a line for a path, you'll have to refactor a lot of your code, and create the "d" attribute for the path.